# How to force Windows to send 'LOW_MEMORY' signal to all applications?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, low-memory

I'm working on some "free RAM" tool that has to force windows to send `'LOW_MEMORY'` signal to all applications (that asks all application to free their unused data, SQL server and file caches get cleared so you'll end up with lots of extra free space).

**What will be best approach to do it in C++?** The most "natural" solution for me would be to allocate a big amount of memory, but is it a "good" and "stable" way? Maybe there is any c++ Windows native function for it in WinAPI or somewhere else?

p.s.
The concept of that tool came from (and I know that better way is to... buy some RAM, but I have to write such tool now):

https://superuser.com/questions/214526/how-does-a-free-up-ram-utility-free-up-ram

Comment: Why are you using/writing such tool? Your operating system automatically frees up RAM when needed.

Comment: ... and reading the linked question should have given you the idea already that such a tool in general isn't really doing you any good

Comment: I write it because company I am working for made me to write it. So there is "no discussion" about it ;) And I know that most of such programs (like CClenaer etc.) do it that way too. So I just want to send that signal to Windows's applications in C++, even when it's a bit pointless in result.

Comment: When you say "LOW_MEMORY" message, are you talking about the event associated with [`CreateMemoryResourceNotification `](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366541.aspx)?

Comment: Just some tips: I think the problem of internal memory management is in the NT API not in the WIN32 layer/subsystem... You may also take want to search using depends.exe from Microsoft support tools.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possibility could be to iterate thru the active process list, and ask each one to trim it's working set, via [SetProcessWorkingSetSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686234%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)( hProcess, (SIZE_T)-1, (SIZE_T)-1), as described [here on MSDN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/293215), potentially skipping applications if your intent is to attempt to improve performance of some particular application (benchmarking is absolutely your friend here).

This causes the OS to flush virtual pages to disk, freeing up physical memory for other applications.  I'm not sure if this will cause, e.g., SQL Server to relax it's memory demands, but it is certainly worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few links which may be of use to you at MSDN:

- [freeing user physical pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366566%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [global free function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366579%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [local free function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366730%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [heap free](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366701%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Hopefully these can give you a start.  The other way you could free up ram is to signal windows to page every processes RAM allocation to swap file, which will free physical RAM up.  Then as the user uses a particular application it will be moved back to physical ram by the OS, that way the management is still handled for the most part by the OS.

Comment: Voted for "up" to neutralize it ;) Sad that I could not mark both your answers, but I have to choose and James Hugard gave an solution, still you gave an great point to start deeper research.

Comment: Thanks for the vote up:)  was honestly just curious, love James' answer, nice, concise and OS friendly way to do flushes to virtual ram.